# Is the phrase "through our choice of words" redundant?

Tags: meaning

What extra information does the phrase "through our choice of words" provide in the text below?

> This book follows most modern course books in using the term 'tense' to refer to the large variety of forms we use to convey information about time **through our choice of words**.

To my understanding, the choice of words really means the choice of verb forms in different tenses, and I feel like it won't affect the meaning of this sentence if I drop the phrase.

Source: *Grammar for English Language Teachers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm inclined to agree with you that those words are (very nearly) redundant.

I use the "very nearly" caveat to allow for the fact that maybe the author is aware of one or more alternative methods of conveying information about time *other than* "through our choice of words", and he wants to make sure that we, the readers, understand that we are not considering those alternatives. But I parenthesized that caveat because I don't really believe it, for two reasons:

**First**: given what is being said, it seems to me that those last five words are serving the very same role as the word "forms" earlier in the sentence. Consider:

> This book follows most modern course books in using the term 'tense' to refer to the large variety of word choices we use to convey information about time.

But **second**, and more problematic, what *exactly* is the intended force of "choice of words"; i.e. as opposed to *what*? Consider the following:

> This book follows most modern course books in using the term 'tense' to refer to the large variety of forms we use to convey information about time **by the extent to which taboo phrases are deployed**.

which I suppose is plausible, but...no;

> This book follows most modern course books in using the term 'tense' to refer to the large variety of forms we use to convey information about time **by varying the typeface used**.

which is silly;

> This book follows most modern course books in using the term 'tense' to refer to the large variety of forms we use to convey information about time **through our choice of marks made with a pen on paper**.

which is just daft.